# How to get all processes that are using a file and kill them in C#

Tags: c#, process

I have a shared SQLite database file. My desktop application uses this file and sends data into it and then copies it to my windows mobile device. Then my windows mobile does some process on its data.

When the job is done, my desktop application wants to get the file. Sometimes the file will not copy.

> The error is `file is in use`.

I open and close connection in data layer.Here is sample method in my Handheld application:

```
public DataView GetDataView(string command)
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString_SQLite);
        SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command, con);
        DataTable dt = null;
        try
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt.DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            //throw x;
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();

            con = null;
            sda = null;
            dt = null;

            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Moreover the error is rising only in ten percents of cases so the problem is not from `SQLiteConnection`. The connection to Handheld is OK because I can browse to the drive created by Active-Sync and see my device's files.

Restarting the device will solve the error but this is not what I and my customer want.
I know the problem is my application but I don't know how to solve it. here is my PC-application code to get the file:

```
private bool GetFileFromHH()
    {
        OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI rapi = new OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI();

        try
        {
            rapi.Connect();

            if (!rapi.DeviceFileExists(Constant.SqliteDBPath_Device))
            {
                msg.MessageBox(
                "The database file on handheld was not found.",
                "",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                DLL3.ShowMessage.IconStyle.Copy);
                return false;
            }

            rapi.CopyFileFromDevice(Constant.SqliteDBPath_PC, Constant.SqliteDBPath_Device, true);

            DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(Constant.SqliteDBPath_PC);
            DI.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            msg.MessageBox(
                x.Message,
                "",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                DLL3.ShowMessage.IconStyle.Copy);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I test some approaches and it is clear to me that the file on handheld is in use by my application but I don't know which application, the `HH-app` or `PC-app`.
Is there any way to close all processes on the file or force copy or something else?

Determination the application is a great help by its self and the killing it will complete my request.

Comment: You're asking for the wrong solution to this problem. Many tools exist that can show you which process has a file in use. It's either your application, or something like a virus scanner. If the former, show your code. When the latter is true, add an exclusion to the virus scanner. You say _"the problem is not from connection"_, but there's no way for us to prove that.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster for your answer. 

Yes the connection is OK because I can browse to the drive created by Active-Sync and see my device's files. I turned off my virus scanner and tried again but the problem exists. So the problem is my application. I have updated my post, please check it out. Thanks...